# Visual Studio nuget command error code -1

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, nuget

In Visual Studio, when I try to build a certain solution I get the following 2 errors: `The system cannot find the path specified` and `The command ""path\to\solution\.nuget\NuGet.exe" install "path\to\project\tobeusedas\reference\packages.config" -source ""  -NonInteractive -RequireConsent -solutionDir "path\to\solution\ "" exited with code -1.` I'm using visual studio 2013, .NET 4.5.1 and I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling NuGet, Visual Studio and .Net. I've also compared NuGet.Config and NuGet.targets to a working solution and found no differences. Why is this error happening?

**Edit** I added a local user to my machine, added a fresh install of Visual Studio and this time I got the kind of errors I was expecting and could deal with. The project compiles now on my local account. So somehow my Visual Studio profile on my domain account was causing me to get this weird error.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know without looking at your project file but it looks like it's a flavor of Automatic Package Restore.  The old package restore used to add .nuget\nuget.exe to source control for each solution and modify the project files to call it.  So it's possible that the project file was setup with the old package restore but nuget.exe isn't in the .nuget folder.  If that's happening, you should consider migrating to the latest method of package restore since you're using VS 2013.

http://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore/migrating-to-automatic-package-restore
http://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore

Comment: I do have NuGet.exe in the .nuget folder. Thanks